# Getting the updated date and time of each country (in vb6)

Tags: datetime, vb6, command-prompt

I want the date and time via the Internet to **get a country.**

And then I set my system date and time.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, and briefly state what you're trying to do. Also, both pieces of code seem identical (I diff-checked them)

Comment: I ask the other person has changed.

Comment: Let me see if I understand right: **1)** You get the date & time from the Internet; **2)** You want to know from which country this date & time comes; **3)** Knowing this, you want to adjust your system date & time accordingly, using your own time zone information.